# Android Camera2 API SecurityException

Tags: android, camera, android-permissions, android-camera2

I'm trying to use the new Android camera2 api.  I started with source from this tutorial : http://jylee-world.blogspot.com/2014/12/a-tutorial-of-androidhardwarecamera2.html .  When I try to usb-debug-deploy it to any phone, I get a SecurityException from `CameraManager.openCamera(...)`.

My AndroidManifest looks like this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="com.android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

This seems to be what every tutorial I've been able to find does. I'm able to get permission for other actions; for example, I can make the camera vibrate just fine.  I'm also able to enumerate cameras with `CameraManager.getCameraIdLists()` just fine, but I'm not sure if that actually requires permission. But I can't `openCamera`.

Are there some additional permissions I need?  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for the help!

This is my full stack trace:

```
SecurityException
java.lang.SecurityException: Lacking privileges to access camera serviceat android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:108)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.CameraDeviceUserShim.connectBinderShim(CameraDeviceUserShim.java:336)
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:327)
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCamera(CameraManager.java:457)
        at com.example.quinnfreedman.camera2test.MainActivity$1.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(MainActivity.java:74)
        at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:368)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15167)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3612)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3402)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15185)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3612)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3402)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15185)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3612)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3402)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15185)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3612)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3402)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16197)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15190)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2627)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2446)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2079)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: Do you run the app on Android 6 ?

Comment: @Alex yes, I'm running it on 6.1

Comment: Have you asked for a permission ? If your app target's API 23 then you need to ask for permission. Or at least for this test you need to go to setting and grant the permission if you don't want to implement extra stuff right now. But you will have to later

Comment: @Alex Thanks, that looks like the issue.  This is my first time using 23 ...I wonder why other permissions seemed to work.

Comment: Now there are dangerous and non dangerous permissions. You should read about them.

Comment: I suggest you to read my answer, its much easy to handle the permissions =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android M, run time permission check is required for dangerous permission. You can see dangerous permission [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous).

Check for permission :

```
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
```

If the app has the permission, the method returns `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`, and the app can proceed with the operation. If the app does not have the permission, the method returns `PERMISSION_DENIED`, and the app has to explicitly ask the user for permission.

For details: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request

Answer (score 1):

Just close your camera device in onSurfaceTextureDestroyed function

```
 onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture){cameraDevice.close();cameraDevice = null;}
```

Security exception will get fix

Comment: Can you explain it better? Why does closing the camera with `cameraDevice.close()` will not throw the security exception?

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your application on android 6+, you need to give the famous runtime permissions.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

The permission you are trying to give is considered a dangerous permissions android.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Different of other responses about runtime permission, I suggest you to use this https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

This lib makes the permission handling easily

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this off and on for weeks, thinking several times I'd solved the problem. In the end, none of the "fixes" I'd read about here worked. Then, after putting in ~100 Log.v statements in my Java, I realized it was a threading issue that might, or might not, kick off this error depending on events on the camera. Basically, I think, the main program was running on the main thread, but there was an extra thread kicked off by the following statement:

```
//this code seems to be the culprit  ... commenting it out solve my problem
private void showToast(final String text) {
    final Activity activity = MyStupidProgram.this;
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So while there's nothing in this statement calling the camera, perhaps because of thread safety, Android 5.x and 6.x were throwing security errors when I called showToast('some crap');

Commenting that out and just using a Toast.makeText('blah blah'); statement, I was able to get rid of the security error.

Additionally, I added this to the code on the page's onCreate(); statement, to catch any issues on the main thread:

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(
                        Thread paramThread,
                        Throwable paramThrowable
                ) {
                    //Do your own error handling here

                    if (exceptionHandler != null)
                        exceptionHandler.uncaughtException(
                                paramThread,
                                paramThrowable
                        ); //Delegates to Android's error handling
                    else
                        System.exit(2); //Prevents the service/app from freezing
                }
            });
```